# tinybutstrong html to word document

Tags: php, html, ms-word, tinybutstrong

Is there a way to convert a HTML formmatted string to a Word document? I tried using tinybutstrong but it doesn't seem to convert any html tags.

Comment: tbs is a templating system, no relation to word document generation...  Did you try http://www.phpdocx.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

TinyButStrong is a PHP template engine that can merge HTML, Text, ... and also Docx, Xlsx, Odt, Ods, ... using it's OpenTBS plugin.
Nevertheless it cannot to conversion.

Maybe here is a solution:
http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/08/13/convert-docx-doc-rtf-to-html-in-php/